# Center middle image on breakpoint using flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a container that has three images. Two on the left side and one on the right side on the mobile layout. When I hit a larger breakpoint, I want the image in the middle to be centered. I have been trying to do solve this using flexbox but I'm not able to center the image. I know it can be done using `position: absolute` but I was wondering if there's a way to do it with flexbox.

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
}
.left {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.back {
  height: 20px;
}
.logo {
  height: 30x;
}

@media (min-width: 640px){
  .left {
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <img class="back" src="https://placeimg.com/20/20/animals"/>
    <img class="logo" src="https://placeimg.com/200/50/animals"/>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/100/20/animals"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: which image actually you want to make center all images or just logo image.

Comment: Do you mean the center of the logo should be at the center of the container or centered between the left/right image?

Comment: Also, is it allowed to change the markup some?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `margin:0 auto;` to `.logo` in large screen sizes.

```
@media (min-width: 640px){
   .logo{
      margin:0 auto;
   }
}
```

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
}
.left {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.back {
  height: 20px;
}
.logo {
  height: 30x;
}

@media (min-width: 640px){
  .logo{
    margin:0 auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <img class="back" src="https://placeimg.com/20/20/animals"/>
    <img class="logo" src="https://placeimg.com/200/50/animals"/>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/100/20/animals"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`justify-content: space-between;` in flexbox make the first item is on the start line, last item on the end line so that not what you want.

You have two options : 
1- you can use `margin: 0` auto for the .logo and it will ok.

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
}
.left {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.back {
  height: 20px;
}
.logo {
  height: 30x;
}

@media (min-width: 640px){
  .logo{
    margin:0 auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <img class="back" src="https://placeimg.com/20/20/animals"/>
    <img class="logo" src="https://placeimg.com/200/50/animals"/>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/100/20/animals"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

2- you can give `.right{ flex-grow: 1;}` on the bigger screen so the image on left will be already centered and on smaller device just remove it.

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
}
.left {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.back {
  height: 20px;
}
.logo {
  height: 30x;
}

@media (min-width: 640px){
  .right {
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: right;
  }
  .left{
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <img class="back" src="https://placeimg.com/20/20/animals"/>
    <img class="logo" src="https://placeimg.com/200/50/animals"/>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/100/20/animals"/>
  </div>
</div>
```